# str not callable en una situación muy peculiar

Tags: python, diccionarios

He estado intentando escribir un código que halle las 15 palabras más repetidas de un texto, y, después de lograr mi cometido, me encuentro con una situación muy peculiar. Estoy escribiendolo en Colaboratory, y, al correr el código en un cuaderno "de prueba" (uno donde solo está este código) lo hace sin mayor complicación. Pero al correrlo en uno donde he escrito otros códigos, me lanza un error.
El código es el siguiente:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(*"Este programa hallará las 15 palabras más repetidas en un texto. Porceda a introducir un texto")
texto = input()
#Quitamos los signos de puntuacion.
remplazar = ",;.:-\n!¡'?¿+-/%#*()"
for signo in remplazar:
  texto = texto.replace(signo, " ")
#Lo convertimos todo a minúscula para que todas las palabras se cuenten por igual.
texto = texto.lower()
#Una vez que el texto está "depurado", procedemos a convertirlo todo a una lista en la que cada palabra es un objeto. Esro facilita mucho las cosas
palabras = texto.split()
#Ahora, contamos las palabras usando un diccionario.
veces = dict()
for palabra in palabras:
  if palabra in veces:
    veces[palabra] += 1
  else:
    veces[palabra] = 1
veces = sorted(veces.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
print(*"Las palabras que más se repiten  y la cantidad de veces, son las siguientes.")
for i in range(15):
  print(veces[i])
```

Y me lanza el siguiente error al correrlo en el segundo cuaderno:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-16-e5b8652e654f> in <module>()
      1 from operator import itemgetter
----> 2 print("Este programa hallará las 15 palabras más repetidas en un texto. Porceda a introducir un texto")
      3 texto = input()
      4 #Quitamos los signos de puntuacion.
      5 remplazar = ",;.:-\n!¡'?¿+-/%#*()"

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

¿A qué se debe esto? ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Es curioso que te salga un error en un `print`

Comment: Según yop, te deberia de dar error en el último `for` al mostrar las palabras

Comment: Elimina el asterico en el argumento de los `print`.

Answer (score 0):

El error nos dice que estás intentando hacer una llamada a una string.
Esto significa que tienes una variable que es una string y se está intentado acceder a su método `__call__`.
Obtendremos este error con este pequeño código

```py
mi_string = ""
mi_string("Hola mundo")
```

En Python poner paréntesis detrás de un símbolo es una llamada.
Por lo tanto tienes en tu código una variable string a la que le has añadido unos paréntesis detrás.
Como además el intérprete nos dice que el error está en la línea:

```py
print("...")
```

en este punto el error debería ser evidente.
El único símbolo al que estás llamando en esa línea es `print`.
Por lo tanto `print` es una string.
Probablemente en algún punto del código has definido una string `print = "..."`.
Al hacer esto la función built in `print` ha quedado escondida.
Para evitar este problema reinicia tu cuaderno de jupyter y recuerda siempre evitar dar nombres built in a tus variables.

Como tú has dicho, si corres el código en un cuaderno *virgen*, la función `print` seguirá disponible y tu código no debería lanzar ningún error.